# customization on emmet's snippets.json file

Tags: vim, emmet

ENV:debian+vim+emmet.

1. no backslah at the end of tag when to expand abbreviation

   Here is link abbreviation on my .vim/snippets.json file.

   ```
   "link": "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"\" />",
   ```

   When to expand `link` in emmet, i get the below output:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
   ```

   Why can't get

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
   ```

   as output?
2. fail to customize script tag

   I expect to expand `script` as `<script src="" type="text/css"></script>`

   ```
   sudo vim .vim/snippets.json
   "script": "<script !src=\"\">",
   ```

   1. What does ! here mean?
   2. to rewrite

      ```
      "script": "<script !src=\"\">",
      ```

      as

      ```
      "script": "<script src=\"\" type=\"text/javascript\">",
      ```

      It take no effect when to reboot vim.

      No `<script src="" type="text/css"></script>` as expand of `script`.

Comment: If you have problems with a particular plugin, its author is the best resource; email him or open an issue in the accompanying issue tracker, if there is any. And why do you need `sudo` to modify your personal Vim configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vim .vimrc
let g:emmet_html5 = 0
```